# Why does VueJS doesn't print out when it's on the Website but works locally

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a simple VueJS file that get a list of Leads with their profile picture and their names. And it works locally. But when I paste the same code on a Website the behaviour is kinda odd. The profile picture still gets displayed, but when it comes to the other values it's not displaying anything even though I know that the data is filled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body style="background-color: black;"> 
    <div id="app" class="container"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
    <script>
        const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

        const App = {
            setup() {

                const leads = ref([{
                    "Profile": "https://wallpapers.com/images/featured/cool-profile-picture-87h46gcobjl5e4xu.jpg",
                    "Firstname": "Andra",
                    "Lastname": "Krasnique",
                    "Commitment": "Junior",
                    "Industry": "Medtech"
                }])

                return {
                    leads
                };
            },
            template: `
            <div class="container mt-6 is-flex is-align-items-center is-flex-direction-column">
                <span v-for="lead in leads" class="lead">
                    <span class="lead__head">
                        <img :src="lead.Profile" class="profile" style="height: 10rem" />
                        <span class="lead__head__title"> 
                            <span class="is-size-3 has-text-weight-bold" :class="lead.Firstname">{{ lead.Firstname }} {{ lead.Lastname }}</span>
                            <span class="is-size-5">{{ lead.Commitment }}<span v-if="lead.Industry"> · {{ lead["Industry"] }}</span></span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="lead_interest">
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        `,
        };

        createApp(App).mount("#app");
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown where this data comes from. The obvious explanation is that it differs in some way for some reason

Comment: It shows on my machine :P. Background is black and text is black. Is this by any chance your issue?

Comment: It is also working locally but running on a server doesn't work.

Comment: Use [vue JS developer tools for Chrome](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) to see the problem, it helps you inspect the data. Also check your browser console for errors. Please post any errors in the question as text.

Comment: I didn't find anything suspicious here but feel free to check this page where I'm using that code: https://www.startglobal.org/cfm?hs_preview=qwAgLPWV-159023825479&attendeeId=1421061